# Checking if the cell is empty and updating the cell value if empty with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So i am trying to get users to submit times to a spreadsheet and have it update an external workbook. The updating works fine but what i cannot get working is the If statement before the external workbook closes that checks if the cell you are updating is empty or not first.
If the cell is empty, go ahead and update, otherwise return Message.

Code so far: Gets Runtime Error 424 (Object Required)

```
Private Sub submit_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:="Test_Book.xlsx"
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim fDate As Date
Dim rw As Long
Dim srchRange As Range
Dim book2Name As String, book2 As Workbook

book2Name = "Test_Book.xlsx"    ' Name of Source File
Set book2 = Workbooks(book2Name)

fDate = Format(CDate(Month.Text & "/" & Day.Text & "/2015"), "dd/mm/yy")
fTime = Format(Hour.Text & ":" & Min.Text, "hh:mm")

Set srchRange = book2.Sheets("TB").Range("B:B")    ' Search Range

If Application.CountIf(srchRange, fDate) Then
    rw = Application.Match(CLng(fDate), srchRange, 0)   ' Return row of result
Else
    MsgBox Format(fDate, "dd/mm/yy") & " not found."
End If

sCell = book2.Sheets("TB").Range("D" & rw)

If IsEmpty(sCell.Value) Then
sCell.Value = fTime
Else
MsgBox ("There is already a time in this cell")
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks("Master_Timesheet.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: If IsNothing(sCell.Value2) Then...    Or you could try: If IsEmpty(sCell.Value2) Then

Comment: "what i cannot get working" - _what_ isn't working? You need to clarify this.

Comment: @JeremyThompson did you mean `IsEmpty()`? :)

Comment: Updated question with the IsEmpty() function. Same as the code beforehand it returns Runtime Error 424 (Object Required)

Answer (score 0):

sCell is not an object, its a variant containing a value:

Try

```
    Dim sCell as range
    Set sCell=book2.Sheets("TB").Range("D" & rw)
    If IsEmpty(sCell) then
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Works now.